# Why doesn't Intellisense work with unity scripts?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

When i program scripts for unity via Visual Studio, no code complete appears for unity functions. also, no errors appear when i, say, forget a semicolon  or something.

i tried reinstalling the vs unity plugin, no change.

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps to solve the problem:

1. Close visual studio.
2. Go to Edit < Preferences < External Tools in unity.
3. Change the External Script Editor like this:
   [image]
4. Try again in the visual studio.